# Teen Sci Fi book from the mid to late 80s. Young boy is staying with an alien family

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

I am trying to find a book.

- The cover was possibly red, title possibly in yellow. Font was definitely [LCD Mono](https://www.dafont.com/lcd-lcd-mono.font)
- The theme of the story was a human boy who was, for some reason, on an alien planet, staying with an alien family
- The alien species (native to the planet) had vertical breathing tubes coming out of the top of their head.

I am in the UK, no idea if the book was British or American. I read it in '86, '87, '88 or '89. Was probably published around then.

EDIT: Thanks Valorum - boy was aged 8-14 not sure. May have been an older brother too, staying with a different alien family. Not sure how he got there. Aliens didn't look human. The book was for young teens I think. The theme may have been escape, and that may have even been a word in the title but I'm not sure.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add. For example, how old was the boy? What was his name? Did the aliens look human other than the breathing tubes? how did he get to the planet? Was the book for adults or children?